# Checking domain.com:port connecivity

Tags: c#, .net, http, web-crawler, ping

I'm trying to check the connectivity to a website through a specific port i'm just trying this code for now but it's returning either an error or not returning nothing at all.

```
string check_Connectivity(string _HostURI)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(_HostURI)) ;
                    {
                        return _HostURI;
                        MessageBox.Show("Alright " + _HostURI);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                if (ex.ToString().IndexOf("Unauthorized") > -1)
                {
                    return _HostURI;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("some error");
                    return null;
                }
            }
    } //I'm allowing 'unauthorized response' 'cause it also means the port is opened and listening to connections.
check_Connectivity("http://domain[dot]com:3921");
```

## Exception:

It takes about 10/15 seconds without nothing on screen then gives me this :

```
 >---------------------------
    >
    >---------------------------
    >System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected >error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed >because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
    >
    >   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 >readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    >
    >   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, >AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

    >   at >System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken >message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    >
    >   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, >AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, >Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult >lazyResult)
>
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
>
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext >executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean >preserveSyncCtx)
>
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, >ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, >ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
>
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(String address)
>
>   at myAppName.fcontainer.check_Connectivity(String _HostURI) in   >c:\AppPath\Form1.cs:line 113
```

Comment: WHat exceptions are you getting when you get "some error"?

Comment: you know `domain.com:3921` is not exactly a valid url, right?

Comment: @Joe , please check the edit.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Yes, i'll edit it just used it for an example it should be like `http:// domain.com:3921`

Comment: So were you actually trying http://domain[dot]com:3921 or a different URL?  And were you trying an HTTP URL or an HTTPS one?

Comment: ..because this code is trying to do SSL/TLS negotation to whatever URL you provided.

Comment: I tried to ignore the certificates errors, but with no success.
I used this for that `ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`